# reposition image within a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need some pointers in uploading an image and then providing the ability to drag the image around so it fits as desired within another image shape.  Here's what I have so far:

http://goehints.com/public/   <--upload any image
After hitting submit, I can use the top image to select and crop - but I would like to resize/reposition directly within the hex shape.  Any suggestions?

I believe all the code can be viewed from source, let me know if otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a canvas and its "clip" operation:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.createElement("img");
var imgpos = { x:0, y:0, scale: 1.0 };

function redraw() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        var t = 2*Math.PI*(i+0.5)/6;
        var x = 200 + 200*Math.cos(t);
        var y = 200 + 200*Math.sin(t);
        if (i == 0) ctx.moveTo(x, y); else ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.translate(imgpos.x, imgpos.y);
    ctx.scale(imgpos.scale, imgpos.scale);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
}
```

I'm basically drawing the image clipped to an hexagon and then I'm also drawing the hexagon border. The image is also drawn after applying a translate/scale transformation.

This allows you to do all the scale/cropping dynamically in the page, without having to do anything on server side:

```
img.onload = redraw;
img.src = "cube.jpg";

var tracking = null;
canvas.onmousedown = function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
    var x = event.x, y = event.y;
    canvas.onmousemove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
        imgpos.x += event.x - x;
        imgpos.y += event.y - y;
        x = event.x; y = event.y;
        redraw();
    };
    canvas.onmouseup = function() {
        canvas.onmouseup = canvas.onmousemove = null;
    };
};
canvas.onmousewheel = function(event) {
    var d = event.wheelDelta;
    while (d >= 120) {
        imgpos.scale *= 1.1;
        d -= 120;
    }
    while (d <= -120) {
        imgpos.scale /= 1.1;
        d += 120;
    }
    redraw();
};
```

You can see it working [here](http://raksy.dyndns.org/hexcrop/crop.html).

Comment: Ah this is great!  Do I then use the new X and Y coordinates to help resize/crop the image to make it permanent?

Comment: @user1615573: yes the idea is that you can send the final X/Y/scale factors to your server side so that the specific final image can be computed if this is what you need. As an alternative you could just keep the original image instead and remember x/y/scale and then just use the same clipped-draw logic when you need to paint it... but if this is or not a good idea it really depends on what you need the image for.